# How to display <apex:repeat> row background with alternative colour?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am facing aProblem.I want to show a table having row with alternative background color.i am displaying data using .I cant use pageblocktable or any other table method .I have to complete my problem with apex repeat only .
Please anyone Suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS approach is the best way to go. But if for some reason you can't do that, be aware that there is an [apex:variable](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_variable.htm) tag that you can use for things like loop counters or this sort of logic.

Example controller:

```
public class A {
    public String[] values {
        get {
            return new String[] {'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd'};
        }
    }
}
```

and page with alternating color table rows:

```
<apex:page controller="A">
    <table>
    <apex:variable var="color" value="red"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!values}" var="value">
        <tr style="background-color: {!color}"><td>{!value}</td></tr>
        <apex:variable var="color" value="{!IF(color == 'red', 'blue', 'red')}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
    </table>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: The only downside here is the bloated view state resulting from the many expressions that will be evaluated as a result of this loop. In fact, the iterator tags consume the most view state per use compared to any other element. However, this certainly does work in a pinch.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to use the CSS Styling like below. Nothing else is required to use along with `<apex:repeat>`

```
<style>
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: red;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: ya this is a solution , but valid only for some limited browser ...